# label is getting cropped in bar chart when bar is touching the top value

Tags: android, kotlin, bar-chart

how can handle the lables get inside the bar if there is no space and how can i make it show outside the bar if the bar is too short ?

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

[image]

```
   private fun handleDate(chartData: Chartdata?) {
    val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    val labels = ArrayList<String>()
    val colors = ArrayList<Int>()
    // Create a map to store colors for each unique height (value)
    val colorMap = mutableMapOf<Float, Int>()
    val rupeesPercentageMap = mutableMapOf<Float, String>()



    val dataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Bar Chart")
    dataSet.colors = colors
    // dataSet.colors = ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS.toMutableList()

    // Display values on top of the bars
    dataSet.setDrawValues(true)

    val data = BarData(dataSet)


    // Set a custom value formatter for formatting values above the bars
    dataSet.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            logEGlobal("value :$value")
            return try { rupeesPercentageMap.getValue(value) // Format the value as needed
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                "" // Format the value as needed
            }

        }

    }
    data.setValueTextSize(12f) // text size of values shown on bars
    barChart.data = data



    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true) // show values on top of the bar if it is set to true


    val xAxis = barChart.xAxis
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xAxis.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            val index = value.toInt()
            if (index >= 0 && index < labels.size * 10) {
                return labels[index]
            }
            return ""
        }
    }
    xAxis.textSize = 14f // text size of labels below x axis
    xAxis.labelCount = labels.size // ensures all labels are visible
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false) // hides vertical grid line
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true)
    barChart.xAxis.axisLineColor = Color.parseColor("#26000000")
    barChart.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 4f

    barChart.setScaleEnabled(false) // allows zoom in and out
    barChart.enableScroll()
    barChart.description.isEnabled = false    // Set a description if needed
    barChart.animateY(500) // this animates the graph


    barChart.axisLeft.isEnabled = true
    barChart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f  // this starts y axis from 0
    barChart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 10f  // this set y axis last value
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false) // this disables the labels of axisRight
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false) // this disables the left axis line
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawZeroLine(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true)
    barChart.axisLeft.gridColor = Color.parseColor("#14000000") // setting transparent black color


    barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    barChart.axisRight.axisMinimum = 0f  // this starts y axis from 0
    barChart.axisRight.axisMaximum = 10f  // this set y axis last value
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawZeroLine(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false) // this disables the labels of axisRight
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false)




             //        val legend = barChart.legend // this shows boxes of colors below 
                       the bar chart with label
             //        legend.form = Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE
             //        legend.textColor = Color.BLACK

    barChart.legend.isEnabled = false


    // Refresh chart
    barChart.invalidate()

}
```